# JRuby build tool

Tags: jruby, build-automation

I'm looking for some build automation tool for JRuby project. Result of this project should be some library that can do stuff. I need to use some Java libraries but I want to work with Ruby. So that's why JRuby.

In this stage, I'm looking for build automation tool that can handle dependencies and download them from remote repository.

I could use Maven for this, but I'm interested in other alternatives that could be more fun to work with.

Comment: Are you looking for a build tool or a dependency management tool? or both in one?

Comment: Preferably both. I could use something like Simple Build Tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yeah, if you are looking for something sexier than Mave, SBT is good option.
Other options are:

Gradle - http://www.gradle.org/ -  if you want Groovy rather than scala orientation.

Or Gant - http://gant.codehaus.org/ - for some more in the lines of Ant.

Buildr -  http://buildr.apache.org/ - Is another interesting project

I also came across this dead project - http://raven.rubyforge.org/ - But I wonder if something new came to tackle the same item, i.e. using Rake , the ruby build tool, to build java as well.

Answer (score 2):

From a dependency management perspective only, [jbundler](https://github.com/mkristian/jbundler) is a bridge between Maven and bundler that can help you manage your dependencies, whether they are gems or maven artefacts.